# vkWaitForFences and vkDeviceWaitIdle not waiting

Tags: c++, windows-10, vulkan

I just got a new computer that uses nvidia graphics card (gtx 1060) and when I tried running my program (which worked before) I got a bunch of errors, but mostly fixed. The one problem i have left is, vkWaitForFences() and vkDeviceWaitIdle returns VK_ERROR_DEVICE_LOST. My older computer used an amd graphics card, but was really old and I used an older version of the vulkan sdk, though I dont think that is the problem.

I, of course googled the error, which didn't help me much since there wasn't many people who have had this problem. I found that it may be a problem with drivers, so as suggested, I updated both windows and the nvidia drivers. That didn't really help much. I also traced where the problem occured and it always happens the second time I submit my command buffers. The device lost also happens the second time.

My submit commands function, anyone wondering why result is lol, is because thats the first thing i always write for some fast debugging, and is not really anything serious.

```
    if (m_OldAllocCount == 0 || m_RecordCmdBuffers){
            recordPrimaryCmdBuffer();
        }

        VkResult lol = vkWaitForFences(m_ContextPtr->device, 1, &inFlightFences[current_frame], VK_TRUE, std::numeric_limits<uint64_t>::max());
        if (lol == VK_ERROR_DEVICE_LOST)
            std::cout << "device lost" << std::endl;

        uint32_t imageIndex = 0;
        VkResult result = vkAcquireNextImageKHR(m_ContextPtr->device, m_CurrentWindow->m_SwapChain.swapChain, std::numeric_limits<uint64_t>::max(),
            imageAvailableSemaphore[current_frame], VK_NULL_HANDLE, &imageIndex);

        m_RecordCmdBuffers = false;

        // If swapchain needs recreation
        if (result == VK_ERROR_OUT_OF_DATE_KHR)
        {
            recreateSwapChain(m_CurrentWindow->getWindowSize());
            viewport(Vector2i(0), m_CurrentWindow->getWindowSize());
        }
        else if(result != VK_SUCCESS && result != VK_SUBOPTIMAL_KHR)
            throw std::runtime_error("failed to acquire swap chain image!");

        // Set the correct index to image, for the uniform buffers to send data to correct block
        for (auto& shader : m_CurrentShaders)
        {
            shader->m_UniformBuffers[(int)ShaderStage::VertexBit].m_CurrentImage   = imageIndex;
            shader->m_UniformBuffers[(int)ShaderStage::FragmentBit].m_CurrentImage = imageIndex;
            shader->m_UniformBuffers[(int)ShaderStage::GeometryBit].m_CurrentImage = imageIndex;
        }

        VkSubmitInfo submitInfo = {};
        submitInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SUBMIT_INFO;

        VkSemaphore waitSemaphores[] = { imageAvailableSemaphore[current_frame] };
        VkPipelineStageFlags waitStages[] = { VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT };
        submitInfo.waitSemaphoreCount = 1;
        submitInfo.pWaitSemaphores = waitSemaphores;
        submitInfo.pWaitDstStageMask = waitStages;
        submitInfo.commandBufferCount = m_PrimaryCommandBuffer.size();
        submitInfo.pCommandBuffers = m_PrimaryCommandBuffer.data();

        VkSemaphore signalSemaphores[] = { renderFinishedSemaphore[current_frame] };
        submitInfo.signalSemaphoreCount = 1;
        submitInfo.pSignalSemaphores = signalSemaphores;

        // Reset the fences
        vkResetFences(m_ContextPtr->device, 1, &inFlightFences[current_frame]);

        // Submit the graphics queue
        if (vkQueueSubmit(m_ContextPtr->graphicsQueue, 1, &submitInfo, inFlightFences[current_frame]) != VK_SUCCESS)
            std::cout << "failed to submit command buffer" << std::endl;

        VkPresentInfoKHR presentInfo = {};
        presentInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PRESENT_INFO_KHR;
        presentInfo.waitSemaphoreCount = 1;
        presentInfo.pWaitSemaphores = signalSemaphores;

        VkSwapchainKHR swapChains[] = { m_CurrentWindow->m_SwapChain.swapChain };
        presentInfo.swapchainCount = 1;
        presentInfo.pSwapchains = swapChains;
        presentInfo.pImageIndices = &imageIndex;
        presentInfo.pResults = nullptr;

        result = vkQueuePresentKHR(m_ContextPtr->presentQueue, &presentInfo);

        // If swapchain needs recreation
        if (result == VK_ERROR_OUT_OF_DATE_KHR || result == VK_SUBOPTIMAL_KHR || m_CurrentWindow->windowResized()) {
            vkWaitForFences(m_ContextPtr->device, 1, &inFlightFences[current_frame], VK_TRUE, std::numeric_limits<uint64_t>::max());

            recreateSwapChain(m_CurrentWindow->getWindowSize());
            viewport(Vector2i(0), m_CurrentWindow->getWindowSize());
        }
        else if (result != VK_SUCCESS)
            throw std::runtime_error("failed to present swap chain image!");

        current_frame = (current_frame + 1) % MAX_FRAMES_IN_FLIGHT;

        if (m_AllocCount > 0)
        {
            m_CurrentCmdBuf = 0;
            m_OldAllocCount = m_AllocCount;
        }
```

Here is my output

```
[Run time : 0.00032s][Application]Info:    application version: 4194304
[Run time : 0.00495s][Application]Info:    engine version: 4194304
[Run time : 0.00641s][Application]Info:    api version: 4194304
[Run time : 0.02141s][Validation Layers]Debug:    Validation layers available
[Run time : 1.69485s][Extensions]Info:        VK_KHR_surface
[Run time : 1.69698s][Extensions]Info:        VK_KHR_win32_surface
[Run time : 1.69893s][Extensions]Info:        VK_EXT_debug_utils
[Run time : 3.35121s][Vulkan Instance]Trace:    Succesfully created instance
[Run time : 3.35314s][Vk Validation]Debug:    Added messenger
[Run time : 0.00004s][Application]Info:    application version: 4194304
[Run time : 0.00079s][Application]Info:    engine version: 4194304
[Run time : 0.00144s][Application]Info:    api version: 4194304
[Run time : 0.01320s][Validation Layers]Debug:    Validation layers available
[Run time : 0.01410s][Extensions]Info:        VK_KHR_surface
[Run time : 0.01502s][Extensions]Info:        VK_KHR_win32_surface
[Run time : 0.01580s][Extensions]Info:        VK_EXT_debug_utils
[Run time : 0.06975s][Vulkan Instance]Trace:    Succesfully created instance
[Run time : 0.07116s][Window]Trace:    Succesfully created window surface
[Run time : 0.07216s][GPU]Info:    Found atleast one GPU with vulkan support
[Run time : 0.07302s][GPU]Debug:    [GeForce GTX 1060]
[Run time : 0.07366s][GPU]Debug:        score: 82920
[Run time : 0.07434s][GPU]Debug:        device type: discrete
[Run time : 0.07496s][GPU]Debug:        driver version: 1749598208
[Run time : 0.07558s][GPU]Debug:        vulkan version: 4198484
[Run time : 0.07620s][GPU]Debug:        max viewports: 16
[Run time : 0.07680s][GPU]Debug:        max tesselation level: 64
[Run time : 0.07743s][GPU]Debug:        memory heap count: 2
[Run time : 0.07808s][GPU]Debug:        vendor id: 4318
[Run time : 0.08448s][GPU]Debug:    [Intel(R) UHD Graphics 630]
[Run time : 0.08767s][GPU]Debug:        score: 34816
[Run time : 0.08877s][GPU]Debug:        device type: integrated
[Run time : 0.09002s][GPU]Debug:        driver version: 1644692
[Run time : 0.09115s][GPU]Debug:        vulkan version: 4198482
[Run time : 0.09233s][GPU]Debug:        max viewports: 16
[Run time : 0.09377s][GPU]Debug:        max tesselation level: 64
[Run time : 0.09493s][GPU]Debug:        memory heap count: 1
[Run time : 0.09597s][GPU]Debug:        vendor id: 32902
[Run time : 0.09977s][GPU]Info:    Using discrete graphics [GeForce GTX 1060]
[Run time : 0.67138s][Logical Device]Trace:    Succesfully created logical device
[Run time : 0.95405s][Swap Chain]Trace:    Succesfully created swap chain
[Run time : 0.95670s][Swap Chain]Trace:    Succesfully created image views for swap chain
found obj file(resources/3d-models/common/cube.obj)
size of obj file resources/3d-models/common/cube.obj: 829
found obj file(resources/3d-models/sponza/sponza.obj)
size of obj file resources/3d-models/sponza/sponza.obj: 21109956
found obj file(resources/3d-models/common/example.obj)
size of obj file resources/3d-models/common/example.obj: 51671
[Run time : 28.05996s][Rendering]Trace:    Succesfully created renderpass for swap chain
[Run time : 28.06264s][Rendering]Trace:    Allocated command buffers
[Run time : 28.06549s][Rendering]Trace:    Allocated command buffers
[Run time : 28.06832s][Rendering]Trace:    Allocated command buffers
[Run time : 28.13745s][Uniform Buffer]Debug:    success!, created descriptor set layout for uniform buffer
[Run time : 28.14002s][Uniform Buffer]Debug:    success!, created descriptor pool
[Run time : 28.14322s][Uniform Buffer]Debug:    allocated descriptor sets
[Run time : 28.15548s][Vk Validation]Error:    Shader uses descriptor slot 0.1 but descriptor not accessible from stage VK_SHADER_STAGE_FRAGMENT_BIT
[Run time : 28.16189s][Rendering]Trace:    Succesfully created graphics pipeline
[Run time : 28.16439s][Rendering]Trace:    Allocated command buffers
[Run time : 28.16829s][Uniform Buffer]Debug:    success!, created descriptor set layout for uniform buffer
[Run time : 28.17082s][Uniform Buffer]Debug:    success!, created descriptor pool
[Run time : 28.17548s][Uniform Buffer]Debug:    allocated descriptor sets
[Run time : 28.18030s][Rendering]Trace:    Succesfully created graphics pipeline
[Run time : 28.18263s][Rendering]Trace:    Allocated command buffers
[Run time : 28.18724s][Uniform Buffer]Debug:    success!, created descriptor set layout for uniform buffer
[Run time : 28.18990s][Uniform Buffer]Debug:    success!, created descriptor pool
[Run time : 28.19598s][Uniform Buffer]Debug:    allocated descriptor sets
[Run time : 28.20237s][Rendering]Trace:    Succesfully created graphics pipeline
[Run time : 28.20461s][Rendering]Trace:    Allocated command buffers
submited command buffer
submited command buffer
device lost
[Run time : 28.50525s][Vk Validation]Error:    Cannot call vkDestroyFramebuffer on VkFramebuffer 0x34[] that is currently in use by a command buffer. The Vulkan spec states: All submitted commands that refer to framebuffer must have completed execution (https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.1-extensions/html/vkspec.html#VUID-vkDestroyFramebuffer-framebuffer-00892)
[Run time : 28.50789s][Vk Validation]Error:    Cannot call vkDestroyFramebuffer on VkFramebuffer 0x35[] that is currently in use by a command buffer. The Vulkan spec states: All submitted commands that refer to framebuffer must have completed execution (https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.1-extensions/html/vkspec.html#VUID-vkDestroyFramebuffer-framebuffer-00892)
[Run time : 28.51032s][Vk Validation]Error:    Cannot call vkDestroyFramebuffer on VkFramebuffer 0x36[] that is currently in use by a command buffer. The Vulkan spec states: All submitted commands that refer to framebuffer must have completed execution (https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.1-extensions/html/vkspec.html#VUID-vkDestroyFramebuffer-framebuffer-00892)
[Run time : 28.51312s][Vk Validation]Error:    Cannot call vkDestroyImageView on VkImageView 0x9[] that is currently in use by a command buffer. The Vulkan spec states: All submitted commands that refer to imageView must have completed execution (https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.1-extensions/html/vkspec.html#VUID-vkDestroyImageView-imageView-01026)
[Run time : 28.51778s][Vk Validation]Error:    Cannot call vkDestroyImageView on VkImageView 0xa[] that is currently in use by a command buffer. The Vulkan spec states: All submitted commands that refer to imageView must have completed execution (https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.1-extensions/html/vkspec.html#VUID-vkDestroyImageView-imageView-01026)
[Run time : 28.52056s][Vk Validation]Error:    Cannot call vkDestroyImageView on VkImageView 0xb[] that is currently in use by a command buffer. The Vulkan spec states: All submitted commands that refer to imageView must have completed execution (https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.1-extensions/html/vkspec.html#VUID-vkDestroyImageView-imageView-01026)
[Run time : 28.55500s][Vk Validation]Error:    Attempt to reset VkCommandBuffer 0x2048fbb6340[] which is in use. The Vulkan spec states: commandBuffer must not be in the pending state (https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.1-extensions/html/vkspec.html#VUID-vkResetCommandBuffer-commandBuffer-00045)
[Run time : 28.55764s][Vk Validation]Error:    Attempt to reset VkCommandBuffer 0x2048fb963b0[] which is in use. The Vulkan spec states: commandBuffer must not be in the pending state (https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.1-extensions/html/vkspec.html#VUID-vkResetCommandBuffer-commandBuffer-00045)
[Run time : 28.56087s][Vk Validation]Error:    Attempt to reset VkCommandBuffer 0x2048fb97b10[] which is in use. The Vulkan spec states: commandBuffer must not be in the pending state (https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.1-extensions/html/vkspec.html#VUID-vkResetCommandBuffer-commandBuffer-00045)
[Run time : 28.56487s][Vk Validation]Error:    Attempt to reset VkCommandBuffer 0x2048fb96fd0[] which is in use. The Vulkan spec states: commandBuffer must not be in the pending state (https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.1-extensions/html/vkspec.html#VUID-vkResetCommandBuffer-commandBuffer-00045)
[Run time : 28.57102s][Vk Validation]Error:    Attempt to reset VkCommandBuffer 0x2048fbae220[] which is in use. The Vulkan spec states: commandBuffer must not be in the pending state (https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.1-extensions/html/vkspec.html#VUID-vkResetCommandBuffer-commandBuffer-00045)
[Run time : 28.57564s][Vk Validation]Error:    Attempt to reset VkCommandBuffer 0x2048fbbf4a0[] which is in use. The Vulkan spec states: commandBuffer must not be in the pending state (https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.1-extensions/html/vkspec.html#VUID-vkResetCommandBuffer-commandBuffer-00045)
[Run time : 28.58219s][Vk Validation]Error:    Cannot call vkDestroyRenderPass on VkRenderPass 0x33[] that is currently in use by a command buffer. The Vulkan spec states: All submitted commands that refer to renderPass must have completed execution (https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.1-extensions/html/vkspec.html#VUID-vkDestroyRenderPass-renderPass-00873)
[Run time : 28.58625s][Vk Validation]Error:    Cannot call vkDestroyImageView on VkImageView 0x32[] that is currently in use by a command buffer. The Vulkan spec states: All submitted commands that refer to imageView must have completed execution (https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.1-extensions/html/vkspec.html#VUID-vkDestroyImageView-imageView-01026)
[Run time : 28.59076s][Vk Validation]Error:    Cannot call vkDestroyImage on VkImage 0x30[] that is currently in use by a command buffer. The Vulkan spec states: All submitted commands that refer to image, either directly or via a VkImageView, must have completed execution (https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.1-extensions/html/vkspec.html#VUID-vkDestroyImage-image-01000)
[Run time : 28.59819s][Vk Validation]Error:    Cannot call vkDestroyDescriptorPool on VkDescriptorPool 0x44[] that is currently in use by a command buffer. The Vulkan spec states: All submitted commands that refer to descriptorPool (via any allocated descriptor sets) must have completed execution (https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.1-extensions/html/vkspec.html#VUID-vkDestroyDescriptorPool-descriptorPool-00303)
[Run time : 28.60357s][Vk Validation]Error:    Cannot call vkDestroyDescriptorPool on VkDescriptorPool 0x5d[] that is currently in use by a command buffer. The Vulkan spec states: All submitted commands that refer to descriptorPool (via any allocated descriptor sets) must have completed execution (https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.1-extensions/html/vkspec.html#VUID-vkDestroyDescriptorPool-descriptorPool-00303)
[Run time : 28.61071s][Vk Validation]Error:    Cannot call vkDestroyDescriptorPool on VkDescriptorPool 0x76[] that is currently in use by a command buffer. The Vulkan spec states: All submitted commands that refer to descriptorPool (via any allocated descriptor sets) must have completed execution (https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.1-extensions/html/vkspec.html#VUID-vkDestroyDescriptorPool-descriptorPool-00303)
[Run time : 28.61863s][Vk Validation]Error:    Attempt to free VkCommandBuffer 0x2048fb6d740[] which is in use. The Vulkan spec states: All elements of pCommandBuffers must not be in the pending state (https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.1-extensions/html/vkspec.html#VUID-vkFreeCommandBuffers-pCommandBuffers-00047)
[Run time : 28.62422s][Rendering]Trace:    Succesfully created renderpass for swap chain
[Run time : 28.64659s][Swap Chain]Trace:    Succesfully created swap chain
[Run time : 28.64906s][Swap Chain]Trace:    Succesfully created image views for swap chain
[Run time : 28.65212s][Uniform Buffer]Debug:    success!, created descriptor pool
[Run time : 28.65492s][Uniform Buffer]Debug:    allocated descriptor sets
[Run time : 28.65860s][Uniform Buffer]Debug:    success!, created descriptor pool
[Run time : 28.66277s][Uniform Buffer]Debug:    allocated descriptor sets
[Run time : 28.66672s][Uniform Buffer]Debug:    success!, created descriptor pool
[Run time : 28.66859s][Uniform Buffer]Debug:    allocated descriptor sets
[Run time : 28.67708s][Vk Validation]Error:    VkFence 0x2c[] is in use. The Vulkan spec states: Each element of pFences must not be currently associated with any queue command that has not yet completed execution on that queue (https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.1-extensions/html/vkspec.html#VUID-vkResetFences-pFences-01123)
failed to submit command buffer
```

Comment: You're getting an error message from the validation layers, which means you're doing something that results in undefined behavior. Device loss is a common symptom of undefined behavior. That's the first place you should look; in particular, freeing a command buffer that's still being used by the GPU is very likely to lead to a GPU page fault (just like freeing memory while another thread is accessing it will cause a CPU page fault), and a GPU page fault will usually manifest as device loss.

Comment: I reset the command buffers when I need the swapchain to be recreated. The device loss error is return by vkWaitForFences, to me it seems that that function isn't working since the validations tells me that I'm freeing the command buffer that is in use. For some reason, the swapchain seems to need to be recreated the second time I submit the commands.

Comment: @PeterBjergert: "*I reset the command buffers when I need the swapchain to be recreated.*" You still can't do that while the CB is being used. "*since the validations tells me that I'm freeing the command buffer that is in use*" As Jesse said, you need to fix that. Validation errors are not optional.

Comment: What i meant is that, because of the device loss in vkWaitForFences and vkDeviceWaitIdle, would stop it frow working correctly. Since these errors show up when the swapchain is recreated. Since it's important to only recreate the seapchain when nothing of it is in use. So the validations errors are causef by the device loss earlier.

Comment: Prove that your code is not freeing command buffers that are in use. That is, prove that you're getting device-lost *before* freeing the CBs.

Comment: I updated the output, take a look. This time i set a vkDeviceWaitIdle (instead of vkWaitForFences() function) in the recreateSwapchain() function, there i check whether it returns VK_SUCCESS or VK_ERROR_DEVICE_LOST. But still complains that i am destroying stuff which is in use, keep in mind this code worked on my older computer with an amd gpu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I solved it, apparently the device loss occurred because of the descriptor slot 0.1 thing in my output, the reason I didn't think that was the problem was because it worked on my older computer even though that error popped up. I guess it's different for different GPU's. It now works as expected, thanks for anyone who tried to help.